# My Jquery is valid but how do I get the image to move

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a JSfiddle with some Jquery, CSS and HTML.  when published the button Ids do not move the elephant.  Is the div formation correct?
http://jsfiddle.net/toondog/12u8g51r/4/

```
<pre><body>
 <div class="header">
    <h1>JQuery Assignment</h1>

<input type="button" id="moveRight" value="move right" class=".ele"></button>
<input type="button" id="moveLeft" value="move left" class=".ele"></button>
</div>

<div class="ele">
<img src=http://s26.postimg.org/wlgqr1139/ele2.png>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">



<div class="content">


</div>



</div>

</body>
</pre>
```

Comment: Where is the *elephant*?

Comment: it's the div class ele img source I did a  Jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the wrong element selected, you got an element with class `grad` while your elephant has the class `ele`.

```
$("#moveRight" ).click(function() {
  $(".ele" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});

$("#moveLeft" ).click(function(){
  $( ".ele" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

Also, you didn't load jQuery into your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML in your fiddle had lots of issues (lacking quotes, closing tags which didn't exist etc) and you had not included jQuery in the dropdown on the left. The biggest issue though is that you were trying to animate the `.grad` elements, instead of the `.ele` element. Try this:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>JQuery Assignment</h1>
    <input type="button" id="moveRight" value="move right" class="grad" />
    <input type="button" id="moveLeft" value="move left" class="grad" />
</div>
<div class="ele">
    <img src="http://s26.postimg.org/wlgqr1139/ele2.png" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#moveRight").click(function () {
    $(".ele").animate({
        "left": "+=50px"
    }, "slow");
});

$("#moveLeft").click(function () {
    $(".ele").animate({
        "left": "-=50px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/12u8g51r/5/)